# "Flows through" vs "Flows in"

Tags: prepositions

I got this question:

> River Mahanadi flows _______ Odisha.

Will it be "in or "through"? Had it been a smaller place, like a forest, or a city, I would've chosen "through"; but since the place is Odisha, which is a state in India, can "in" be suitable too? Implying that the river exists in the state Odisha.

Comment: _lies in_ or _is situated in_ Odisha sounds better as does _flows through_ Odisha.

Comment: In multiple choice questions of language, the *correct answer* is the one that works best. The ones that sort of work and are not wrong are not the ones that get credit. So the Mahanadi may flow, exist, and be in Odisha, but *flows through* makes for a richer sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually the case that if a preposition works in a sentence, then any other preposition would also be grammatical. However, which you should use depends on your intent - that isn't something we can reliably predict from the rest of the sentence. Here are some examples:

- The ball bounces on the box.
- The ball bounces in the box.
- The ball bounces through the box.
- The ball bounces behind the box.

Each sentence is grammatical, but they mean different things.

In your example, you are deciding between *in* and *through*.

"In" often carries the idea of boundaries. Saying that the a river flows in Odisha means that within Odisha, the river flows. Perhaps it doesn't flow in the next region. Perhaps it doesn't flow into or out of Odisha. But within Odisha itself, the river certainly flows.

"Through" carries the idea of transition. Saying that a river flows through Odisha implies that the river starts outside Odisha, enters Odisha, then goes out of Odisha.

Comment: I first thought of the “must cross the border” idea too, but it then occurred to me that the river is flowing through the country even if it starts at one point and flows to a different point within the borders.  When blood flows through my veins I certainly don’t want it crossing any boundaries. :-)

Comment: @Jim There is a difference with blood and rivers, though. Blood flows through, ideally, closed systems but river systems are open not only at their source and mouth but also throughout their length. The same blood, pretty much, passes through your heart, lungs and other organs every few minutes but you cannot, in a very real sense, bathe in the same river twice since yesterday's water is long gone.

Comment: @Jim Rivers can be dammed (blocked). At the dam, it doesn’t flow.

Comment: @Lawrence ok, but up until the dam the water was flowing through the country.